# There are currently @count users online translation issue

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

The following string is the default English translation source of the "Who's online counter"

```
There are currently @count users online
```

My site has Arabic language translation. When I tried to translate the above string from `en/admin/config/regional/translate/translate` and when the users number changed to another numbers. I find a new entry like the followings:

- There are currently @count[2] users online.
- There are currently @count[3] users online.

Does this mean that I have to set translation for every number in the digits line?!!! What could I do to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: As you can see there are language args in urls. Think you can translate only /ar for arabic language.

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, but I _think_ this is an issue with the plural formula. You can use [Plural formula configurator](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_pconfig) to set the formula, and if you steal [from the current Arabic Drupal translation](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/translations/7.x/drupal/drupal-7.28.ar.po) the formula is `Plural-Forms: nplurals=6; plural=((n==1)?(0):((n==0)?(1):((n==2)?(2):((((n%100)>=3)&&((n%100)<=10))?(3):((((n%100)>=11)&&((n%100)<=99))?(4):5)))));\n`. I can't help you understand it though!